# Change RDP certificate to SHA-2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I've asked around online at various places but still not got a full answer.

I need to change the RDP certificate on a Server 2012 R2 box to new self signed SHA-2.

Does anyone have a step by step guide?

I tried to install one into MMC\Certifactes\Remote Desktop and delted the exsisting one but it re-appeared on a reboot.